# LWC image from StaticResource not visible in managed package (BETA)

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, images, lightning-card

In LWC lightning-card in standard icon slot I tried to show my custom image instead of an icon. I am getting image from static resources (zip file with logo.png + cache control set to "Public") and all working fine on scratch org but after building BETA managed package and installing on sandbox, I see not rendered image like:

[image: no logo]

My code

- js file

```
import MyImages from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/MyImages'
```

```
myLogo = MyImages + '/logo.png'
```

- html template

```
        <lightning-card variant="Narrow">
            <h3 slot="title">
                <template lwc:if={myLogo}>
                    <img src={myLogo} alt="" class="customIcon" />
                </template>
            </h3>
         </lightning-card>
```

- css

```
    .customIcon{
        width: 26px;
        height: 26px;
        margin-right: 9px;
    }
```

I tried also:

- static resources as .png file (not zip) but the result is the same if I deploy on scratch org - image is visible but after packaging to BETA, not visible anymore
- double-checked that static resource is correctly included in my managed package with cache control set to "Public"

Could you please advice?

Comment: I'd try to prefix the resource with the namespace. See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-resources.html).

Comment: with namespace it is not deployable with error: LWC1504: Invalid module id "nmspce__MyImages" for type "resourceUrl". Explicit use of namespace "nmspce" in file "myComponentjs" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.

Comment: workaround to make it running is via Access Content Asset File https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-content-assets.html